Script with MSOL, AzureADPreview, and ExchangeOnlineManagement suddenly not working in EXE
I made a PowerShell script to process terminations for my company. It uses different modules such as MSOLOnline AzureADPreview and ExchangeOnlineManagement. I would then use ps2exe to convert it to an EXE file so it could be portable for others to use. But recently for some reason it keeps throwing an error when running it from the EXE file and freezing the GUI.
The strange part is I have no issues when running it from VS Code. It had worked for months prior and even if I got back to versions where I know it worked fine previous, myself and others run into the same issue. Currently my theory is that when a command fails, such as a search for a mailbox, it crashes the related services such as ExchangeOnlineManagement. Or if it looks for assigned licenses in Azure and there are none (failed), crashes the AzureADPreview service/connection. At this point though I'm finding it hard to narrow down as the script is about 4000 lines long. Another weird part, is that after loading up the GUI, the script will work for one termination, then get the error when trying the next.
Here are the errors I get on the EXE file and not running straight from VS Code.

ERROR: Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position
0.
ERROR: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc.
This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP
protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being
aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See
server logs for more details

I know these modules are deprecated now, and I'm debating trying to re-create the script on PowerShell 7 with Microsoft Graph. But since we got a bunch of people using this script I'd at least like to get it back up and running.

I've tried different versions of my script, from when I knew it was working.
I've tried re-ordering certain items in the script as I know the connect commands can get funky if called in the middle of a gui.
I've tried to narrow down which command or specific module it could come from with no luck.
I've wondered if somehow my "clear page" button is the problem, since it works for one termination, then freezes on the second. But all it is doing is clearing some variables and textboxes


Id start with catching the exceptions and dumping them to a file for inspection. Something like try{ /* your code */ }catch{$_ | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path ".\exception-log-$((Get-Date).Ticks).txt" } will capture the entire exception object, any inner exceptions, stacktraces etc. Not sure if Start-Transcript and including some Write-Host / Write-Debug / Write-Verbose lines would work with ps2exe - worth a try.

Sounds like something in your environment has changed if older working versions now give the same error - maybe your corporate proxy / antivirus is doing something to the api responses - try running a man-in-the-middle proxy like Fiddler while you’re executing the script and check what the responses contain. The error “Error reading JToken from JsonReader” implies it’s not valid json in any case…
